# Drupal: is Devel module safe for online websites?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is Devel module safe for online websites ?

Can I leave it enabled ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use devel on a production site.

The module itself is safe enough, but the human use of it isn't. It's also quite easy to disable different cache without knowing about it, which can kill your site if you generate too much traffic.

Comment: uhm, ok. But if users do not have permissions to use it, than it is fine right ?

Comment: @Patrick, don't underestimate human error (YOU). But yes in itself, the devel module wont harm your site, it will only open up for the potential to harm it.